# Custom Search and Replace in Notepad++

Tags: utf-8, notepad++, replace

I need to replace certain UTF8 hex codes to the equivalent character in an irregular text string like:

- \C3\A1 á
- \C3\A9 é
- \C3\AD í
- \C3\B3 ó
- \C3\BA ú

I'm not sure if I should be using RegEx or a macro to find and replace each entry since they won't appear regularly in the text strings I'm working with.
Thanks.

Comment: is this a programming question???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a macro - as there's no "variable" data in your search, you don't need a regex.  Record a macro to replace the first character, then the second and so on.  Use the "normal mode" to replace with the correct character.

You need a reasonably new version of N++ to be able to record search & replace actions - from 5.8.2/3 I think.

Dave.